# Combinatorial Proofs with Summation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I've been trying to think up of two combinatorial proofs but I'm confused on the first and just completely stuck on where to begin for the second.

1. $$\sum_{k=-m}^n \binom{m+k}{r}\binom{n-k}{s} = \binom{m+n+1}{r+s+1}$$
   For the RHS, I understand that it is basically looking at the number of $(r+s+1)$ subsets that can be formed from $(m+n+1)$. On expanding the LHS to yield $\binom{0}{r}\binom{n+m}{s}+\binom{1}{r}\binom{n+m-1}{s}...\binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{s}+\binom{m+1}{r}\binom{n-1}{s}+...\binom{m+n}{r}\binom{0}{s}$, I see that it is basically adding together the various ways of drawing a constant $r$ and $s$ from two changing populations that sum up to $m+n$. However, I don't actually see where the $+1$ comes from. Is there anything wrong with my intepretation of the LHS?
2. $$\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)(n-i) = \binom{n}{3}$$
   I know that RHS is counting the number of subsets of 3 that can be formed from $n$. However, I do not have any idea of how to be interpreting the LHS.

Comment: part 2 is a similar vein, but thinking of $(i-1)$ as ${i-1}\choose{1}$ should clear things up.

Comment: @mdave16 I'm not exactly how thinking of $\binom{i-1}{1}$ helps since I'm not exactly sure of how the two product quantities are exactly related.

Comment: think about the hint, then apply to the other multiplicand, then look at part 1... Hmmm 3 = 1 + 1 + 1; n = n - i + i - 1 + 1

Comment: thanks for the second hint!